# copying contents from a variable cell to a fixed cell on another sheet AND hyperlink to fixed cell afterwards

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, copy, cell

Good morning,

I found the following code on the web:

```
function transfer() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
r = s.getRange("A1");
// copyValuesToRange method will copy value in A1 to B1(range of B1 - 2,2,1,1)
r.copyValuesToRange(s,2,2,1,1);
r.clearContent();}
```

I am looking for some help in adapting it slightly.
My end goal is for a user to be able to click on any cell in column A on sheet1! (starting at A3 onwards - A1 and A2 contain text that is not relevant) that has a value and it copies the contents of that cell to sheet2!A1, AND it hyperlinks to sheet2! automatically.

So I am guessing that the getRange needs to become a variable.
And that's me done!

Hopefully, a demigod out there can assist me with this.

Look forward to hearing from you.